# Iphone Converting IplImage to UIImage and back causes rotation

Tags: iphone, opencv, uiimage, iplimage

I am using some code to convert between iplimage and uiimage. I take a photo taken from the camera (a UIImage) and convert it to an iplimage and back using the code posted below. Unfortunately this causes the image to be rotated and stretched by 90 degrees. 
so if I take a 320x480 image it comes back a 320x480 image but the image has been rotated and rescaled so that it looks as if it were rotated 90 degrees (i.e a a 480x320 image) then scaled non-uniformly ... I cannot figure it out -- everything seems right (byte ordering etc.)

```
+(IplImage *)CreateIplImageFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image {
CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
IplImage *iplimage = cvCreateImage(cvSize(image.size.width, image.size.height), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
CGContextRef contextRef = CGBitmapContextCreate(iplimage->imageData, iplimage->width, iplimage->height,
                                                iplimage->depth, iplimage->widthStep,
                                                colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault);
CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height), imageRef);
CGContextRelease(contextRef);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

return iplimage;
}

+(UIImage *)UIImageFromIplImage:(IplImage *)image {
NSLog(@"IplImage (%d, %d) %d bits by %d channels, %d bytes/row %s", image->width, image->height, image->depth, image->nChannels, image->widthStep, image->channelSeq);

CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:image->imageData length:image->imageSize];
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)data);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(image->width, image->height,
                                    image->depth, image->depth * image->nChannels, image->widthStep,
                                    colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,
                                    provider, NULL, false, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
UIImage *ret = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
return ret;
}
```

Comment: i had this error occurs when i attempt to convert IplImage from UIImage <Error>: CGImageCreate: invalid image bits/pixel: 8.
what's the problem?

Comment: Yea I'm getting the same problem as chostDevil.

Comment: Has anyone figured this out?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, too and I still didn't find out how to change the two methods so that they do not rotate the picture.

Instead I rotated the UIImage, e.g. my code looks like this:

```
//Change the rotation here

UIImage *imageCam= [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

//Convert UIImage
IplImage *image = [self CreateIplImageFromUIImage:imageCam];
```

Answer (score 4):

Just change

```
UIImage *ret = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
```

into:

```
UIImage *ret = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found the solution - change `CreateIplImageFromUIImage` like this:

```
- (IplImage *)CreateIplImageFromUIImage:(UIImage *)image {

    CGImageRef imageRef = [self rotateImage:image].CGImage;
        ...........
}

- (UIImage* )rotateImage:(UIImage *)image { 
    int kMaxResolution = 320; 
    // Or whatever     
    CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;
    CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
    CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);     
    if (width > kMaxResolution || height > kMaxResolution) {         
        CGFloat ratio = width  /  height;
        if (ratio > 1 ) {  
            bounds.size.width = kMaxResolution;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width / ratio;
        }
        else {
            bounds.size.height = kMaxResolution;
            bounds.size.width = bounds.size.height * ratio;
        }
    }       
    CGFloat scaleRatio = bounds.size.width / width;
    CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(imgRef), CGImageGetHeight(imgRef));
    CGFloat boundHeight;
    UIImageOrientation orient = image.imageOrientation;
    switch (orient) { 
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
            //EXIF = 1
            transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            break;           
        case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
            //EXIF = 2
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0 );
            break;           
        case UIImageOrientationDown: 
            //EXIF = 3
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.width, imageSize.height); 
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
            break; 
        case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
            //EXIF = 4 
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.height);
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
            //EXIF = 5
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, imageSize.width ); 
            transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1.0, 1.0);    
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0 );
            break;           
        case UIImageOrientationLeft: 
            //EXIF = 6
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, imageSize.width);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate( transform, 3.0 * M_PI / 2.0   );
            break;           
        case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored: 
            //EXIF = 7
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width; 
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1.0, 1.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate( transform, M_PI / 2.0);
            break;           
        case UIImageOrientationRight: 
            //EXIF = 8   
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height;
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width;
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight;
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(imageSize.height, 0.0);
            transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI / 2.0 );
            break;
        default:
        [NSException raise:NSInternalInconsistencyException format:@"Invalid image orientation"];
    }       
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    if (orient == UIImageOrientationRight || orient == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, -scaleRatio, scaleRatio);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -height, 0);
    }     
    else {
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, scaleRatio, -scaleRatio);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, -height);
    } 
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform );
    CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imgRef);
    UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return imageCopy;
}
```